# laravel: Eloquent all() data is missing when converted to json

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Part of data can not be acquired when Eloquent object is set to Json.

1. I use command `artisan make:Auth`, and customized users table.

Specifically, I thought that I did not need to delete the email column once,
but since it became necessary, I added it again.
These operations use a migration file.

2. I got all the data of users table and returned it with Json.

But email is not output.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

Even using `json_encode` did the same thing.

It exists when use this

```
$user = User::all();
$userArray = array();
foreach ($user as $u){
    $userArray[] = [
        'name' => $u->name,
        'email' => $u->email
    ];
}
return $userArray;
```

Why is not email being outputted?

(I rely on google translation)

---

**Additional notes**

Thanks to everyone for comment.
Comparing the output of json with dd(), password and remember_token were not output in addition to email.

Perhaps the email is private property, and private property is a mechanism that does not output JSON?
In that case, how can I change to public?

The User model looks like this

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'email','remember_token',
    ];
~~~
}
```

Comment: try dd($user) first if user object contains email

Comment: I did not know dd (), so I tried it a while ago.
```
$user = User::all();
dd($user[0]);
```
There was email data.

Comment: Just do print_r before looping through your object

Comment: Can you show `User` model?

Comment: try print_r($user) in your view. It might be returning email but you might be trying to access in different way

Comment: I added. Thank you for your review.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself.
I found that the column set here is not output to JSON.

```
protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'email','remember_token',
];
```

It was a very simple thing....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return User::select('name', 'email')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: I try it, but email was not output.(Only name is output.)

Comment: remove email from hidden property of your User model